# Grid Column Ordering

Tags: telerik, radgrid

I have a grid which consists of a queryable datasource and template column.

```
       <telerik:RadGrid ID="rulesGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
      <MasterTableView>
      <Columns>
      <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" UniqueName="statusResult">
       </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
       </Columns>
      </MasterTableView>

     </telerik:RadGrid>
```

And in the page_load

```
     var ruleset = (from s in (this.Page as BasePage).DbContext.ProductEventChecks
                       where s.Sequence!=0
                       orderby s.Sequence
                       select new
                       {
                           Description = s.Description
                       });

        rulesGrid.DataSource = ruleset;
        rulesGrid.DataBind();
```

So, the problem is that status field(template column) comes before the Description field. But I wanted Description to be displayed first. Can you please help me out in finishing this?

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code snippet.

.aspx

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
    AllowPaging="True" OnPreRender="RadGrid1_PreRender" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="true" oncolumncreated="RadGrid1_ColumnCreated">
    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="true" />
    <MasterTableView>

    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    dynamic data = new[] {
            new { ID = 1, Name ="Name1"}
        };

    RadGrid1.DataSource = data;
}
protected void RadGrid1_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.UniqueName == "ID")
    {
        e.Column.OrderIndex = 1;
    }
    else if (e.Column.UniqueName == "Name")
    {
        e.Column.OrderIndex = 0;
    }

}
```